# How do I count three different distinct values and group on an ID in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

So I know MS-Access does not allow `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT....) FROM ...`, but I am trying to find a more viable alternative to the usual standard of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1)
```

My problem is I am trying to do three separate Count functions and group them on ID. If I use the method above, it is giving me the total unique value count for the whole table instead of the total count for only the value of ID. I tried doing

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1 as T2
WHERE T2.ColumnA = T1.ColumnA)) As MyVal
FROM table1 as T1
```

but it tells me I need to specify a value for T1.ColumnA.

The SQL query I am trying to accomplish is this:

```
SELECT ID
COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnA) as CA,
COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) as CB,
COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnC) as CC
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table1 as T2
WHERE T2.ColumnA = T1.ColumnA)) As MyVal
FROM table1 as T1` is not valid syntax in general. Not just Access

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it is not valid. It is referenced in the answer below...

Comment: It starts with a `(`

Comment: I see what you are saying. It was an excerpt of the third line in the query, hence no `SELECT` or other fields before it. I apologize for the confusion on that.

Comment: ooh oh gotcha. I missed that

Answer (score 3):

You can use subqueries.  Assuming you have a table where each id occurs once:

```
select (select count(*)
        from (select columnA
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id
              group by columnA
             ) as a
       ) as num_a,
       (select count(*)
        from (select columnB
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id
              group by columnB
             ) as b
       ) as num_b,
       (select count(*)
        from (select columnC
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id
              group by columnC
             ) as c
       ) as num_c
from <table with ids> as t;
```

I'm not sure if you'll think this is "viable".

EDIT:

This makes it even more complicated . . . it suggests that MS Access doesn't support correlation clauses more than one level deep (might you consider switching to another database?).

In any case, the brute force way:

```
select a.id, a.numA, b.numB, c.numC
from ((select id, count(*) as numA
       from (select id, columnA
             from table1 t1
             group by id, columnA
            ) as a
      ) as a inner join
      (select id, count(*) as numB
       from (select id, columnB
             from table1 t1
             group by id, columnB
            ) as b
      ) as b
      on a.id = b.id
     ) inner join
     (select id, count(*) as numC
      from (select id, columnC
            from table1 t1
            group by id, columnC
           ) as c
     ) c
     on c.id = a.id;
```

Comment: This does not work. It asks me what I want to specify as the parameter value for t.ID, which is the same issue I was having before.